# Adding attribute to Link via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="navv">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">MAPPING</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I want is to loop through each "li" and then add an attribute to that particular Link "a href" inside the "li" which has the class "dropdown"

I have managed to work it out till:

- looping through each "li"
- I have also managed to check that the "li" has a class 'dropdown'

**The only part left is that I cannot manage to add a new attribute to the 'a href' for that particular 'li' that has the class 'dropdown'**

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navv ul li").each(function(index){
        if($(this).hasClass('dropdown')){
         // Adding a new attribute to the link tag  
         // referring to the particular "li" and "a" inside it and adding attribute, but this doesen't work.
         $(this).("a").attr('data-toggle','dropdown');    
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).children("a").attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
```

Answer (score 3):

You code too much! Try this :

```
$("li.dropdown a").attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
```

Also, except if you really need the attribute on the DOM node (because you are selecting it with bracket `[]` selector), use `.data()`:

```
$("li.dropdown a").data('toggle', 'dropdown');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

you are attr to `li` tag you need to find `a` in `li`

```
$(this).find("a").attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
```

---

Better use

```
$("li.dropdown a").data('toggle', 'dropdown');
```

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)